# Specialization of a template function with multiple template parameters in C++ 11

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Cannot figure out why I am getting the compiler errors with the following code:

```
#include <tchar.h>

typedef TCHAR Char;

typedef std::basic_string<Char> String;

template<typename C, typename T>
std::basic_string<C> InternalToString(T val);

template<typename T>
inline std::string InternalToString<char, T>(T val)
{
    return std::to_string(val);
}

template<typename T>
inline std::wstring InternalToString<wchar_t, T>(T val)
{
    return std::to_wstring(val);
}

template<typename T>
inline String ToString(T val)
{
    return InternalToString<Char, T>(val);
}
```

if I compile the code with MSVC 2017 I get "error C2768: 'InternalToString': illegal use of explicit template arguments"

Comment: I believe you are trying to partially specialize the `InternalToString` function and as far as I remember, that is not allowed in C++. Only partial specialization of template types is allowed. Now thinking of how this could be solved though...

Comment: @Maarten Bamelis Probably the only option is to use a class with the static func.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Partial specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization) is not allowed for function templates, it could be used only for class templates.

You can apply function templates overloading with [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae). e.g.

```
// used when C is specified as char
template<typename C, typename T>
inline typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<C, char>::value, std::string>::type InternalToString(T val)
{
    return std::to_string(val);
}

// used when C is specified as wchar_t
template<typename C, typename T>
inline typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<C, wchar_t>::value, std::wstring>::type InternalToString(T val)
{
    return std::to_wstring(val);
}

// used when C is specified as other types
template<typename C, typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<C, char>::value && !std::is_same<C, wchar_t>::value, std::basic_string<C>>::type InternalToString(T val);
```

Comment: Also tag dispatch is a possibility

Comment: +1, also one more option is using partially specialized class with static method instead of free function - this might be more readable than `enable_if` in more complex templates.